# Member duplication when using virtual method

Tags: c++, object, virtual

When passing a pointer to an object whose parent has a virtual function to a method with a parent type, I get strange copying of parent members in the resulting object.

### Child -> Parent -> Child

```
someMethod(Parent * obj);
```

---

```
Parent
virtual ~Parent() {}

Child : public Parent()
```

---

```
Child childobj = new Child();
someMethod(childobj);
```

---

When viewed in memory after being passed through soemMethod, this shows a resulting object that looks like this:

```
DATA[]
parentvar1
parentvar2
Child[]

->Child[]
->childvar1
->childvar2
->Parent[]

->->Parent[]
->->parentvar1
->->parentvar2
```

Why am I seeing parent data being duplicated both at index 0 and at index 2?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very confusing, could you reformulate it and make it more precise? In particular, the last part, this list doesn't make sense...

Comment: `Child childobj = new Child();` I assume `Child* childobj`? "When viewed in memory" How? A debugger? IDE?

Comment: Please submit a complete but minimal example that demonstrates the problem. This doesn't do it for us.

Comment: You will soon find out that if you want answers you will have to formulate your questions so that they are, *at the very least*, understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just taking a guess, because your terminology is very difficult to understand.

I'm guessing you're viewing your data a debugger, such as Visual Studio, and your program is currently within some method of the `Parent` class.

In the debugger, you're seeing data in the `this` object as well as variables on the stack, what you refer to as "index 0".  One of these variables is another `Child` object.  Since `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`, you'll see both the properties of that `Child` as well as the `Parent` properties it inherits (what you refer to as "index 2").

In this case, you're not seeing any copying, you're simply seeing the same data (or perhaps two different instances) from different perspectives in the debugger.